# bash : trying to write a 32bit integer as 4 byte on binary file, end up with 8 byte

Tags: bash, binary

I try to write some headers on a binary file, the rest of operation (bin file merging etc) are on a batch file but apparently batch is no good to write directly on binary files, i could not manage to write anything else than hex representation, so i moved to bash (under cygwin), and after some struggle i can write bytes on the binary file from a 32 bit integer, however it writes 8 bytes instead of 4, each byte is followed by 0x0D.

So here is the bash script:

```
HEXSTR=`printf "%08x" $1`
BYTE1=`echo -n "$HEXSTR" | cut -c 1-2`
BYTE2=`echo -n "$HEXSTR" | cut -c 3-4`
BYTE3=`echo -n "$HEXSTR" | cut -c 5-6`
BYTE4=`echo -n "$HEXSTR" | cut -c 7-8`
echo $HEXSTR
echo $BYTE1 
echo $BYTE2
echo $BYTE3
echo $BYTE4
echo -ne "\x$BYTE4\x$BYTE3\x$BYTE2\x$BYTE1" | dd of="header.bin" bs=1 seek=388 conv=notrunc
```

It takes the ineger as argument, in this case 516877. And here is the output on the terminal

```
C:\size.sh 5168772
004ede84
 0
4e
de
84
8+0 records in
8+0 records out
8 bytes (8 B) copied, 0.0002827 s, 28.3 kB/s
```

and here is the hex view of what has been written on the file:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1aGd.png)

So, i can see the 4 bytes `00 4e de 84` have been written, however they are followed with `0d`, what am i doing wrong?
What I try to do is write `84de4e00` (5168772) at position 388.

Also, I want to point out that I have seen some solutions involving xxd but for some reason this is not recognized on my system (win10 with cygwin) so sadly I cannot use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$1
printf -v esc '\\x%x' \
    $((num%256)) $((num/2**8%256)) $((num/2**16%256)) $((num/2**24))
printf '%b' "$esc" | dd of="header.bin" bs=1 seek=388 conv=notrunc
```

Comment: Sadly, it complains about invalid operator
C:\>sh C:\size.sh 5168772
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\size.sh: line 15: 5168772

Comment: in fact i tested a similar method before (with bitwise operations) and got the same error message, it must be related to windows/cygwin

Comment: @user301880 There is no `line 15` in my script. Please copy and save the exact text and run again.

Comment: the reason is, my code that was in the file uses the line 2 to 13 (it is commented), from what i have seen before the % operator causes this error

Comment: @user301880 Don't run it as `sh file ...`. Either run it as `bash file ...` or save the _exact text_ in a file, make the file executable, and run as `./file ...`. `sh` and `bash` are different shells.

Comment: oh, i see, i copied directly to the .bat file and no more error, however it only copies one byte now : 

printf 'b' "$esc"   | dd of="header1.abs" bs=1 seek=388 conv=notrunc
printf: warning: ignoring excess arguments, starting with `$esc'
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte (1 B) copied, 0.0002767 s, 3.6 kB/s

Comment: tried to change to '\\x%08x' but no luck, one byte written instead of four

Comment: @user301880 Do not change anything. The script is fine. Just copy it **verbatim**.

Comment: yes, i copied as is in the .bat file:    num=5168772
printf -v esc '\\x%02x' $((num%256)) $((num/2**8%256)) $((num/2**16%256)) $((num/2**24))
printf '%b' "$esc" | dd of="header1.abs" bs=1 seek=388 conv=notrunc

Comment: @user301880 Do not give any extension to the file.

Comment: yes, i did that, copied in a new file without extension, called this file in my main .bat, same warning and only 1 byte written. Tested directly from terminal too, same result.

Comment: @user301880 Weird. What is the value of the byte written? Assuming you called it with the argument `5168772`

Comment: yes, that is the value, i just fixed it : printf -v esc '\\x%x'  now it writes 4 bytes on the file as it should. I will accept the answer and please update it with x%x . Thank you for your patient help.

Comment: Replacing `\\x%02x` with `\\x%x` shouldn't make any difference in this context. `02` was just for "pretty-print".  Also `set num=$1` doesn't make any sense at all. It is possible that your `bash` implementation is broken.